# Field type in GIS changing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes

I am a student in GIS, just finishing my first year. For this project I am adding some fields to an attribute table. The field I am trying to add is suppose to be Short Integer. Every time I create the field, when I go to look at field properties after, it has changed to Long. I'm not sure if it matters entirely, but I am just curious as to why this happening in the field?

Comment: What is your data format ? (shp, gbd, ....)

Comment: It is in shp format

Comment: And what width did you specify (numeric types in shapefile all map to string, then back out again, which will alter the field)